# Loop through column C and return to column B the content minus the first X characters

Tags: excel, vba

Goal: If Column C does not start with "XXX*" then Return that cell minus the first 5 characters.

Example:

```
C2 = XXX                 Then                 B2 would be empty
C3 = YYY1220190318       Then                 B3 = 20190318
C4 = UGA1535D            Then                 B4 = 1535D
```

'Here is my Actual Code

```
  Dim arrData As Variant, LastRow As Long, i As Long, ws As Worksheet

            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Long List 15032019") 'change 

the name of the sheet to the one you are doing the code

        With ws
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
            arrData = .Range("A2", .Cells(LastRow, "C")).Value
            For i = 1 To UBound(arrData)
                If arrData(i, 3) Like "Bus*" Then
                    arrData(i, 1) = "BU CRM"
                Else
                    arrData(i, 1) = "CSI ACE"
                End If
                If arrData(i, 3) Like "CSI*" Or arrData(i, 3) = vbNullString Then
                    arrData(i, 2) = vbNullString
                    Else: arrData(i, 2) = Right(arrData(i, 3), 12)
                End If
            Next i
            .Range("A2", .Cells(LastRow, "C")).Value = arrData

             End With
```

I think it's a single line of code that needs to be adjusted `Else: arrData(i, 2) = Right(arrData(i, 3), 12)`

I did attempt to use -12 or LEFT. But it would not work.

Comment: I was watching at the code and thinking... dude that looks like mine and it was... hahaha you need to take the characters dynamic. `Right(arrData(i, 3), Len(arrData(i, 3) - 5)` that 5 is the characters you want to substract

Comment: @Damian, I'm nearly certain that it is your code, thank you. I did edit the code but it gave me an error. Compile Error -- syntax error

Comment: I guess it happens on strings lesser than 6 characters, if so it will give error. Check it out, if it's that then just use an if statement, `If Len(arrData(i, 3) < 6 Then` whatever if it has 5 or less characters `Else` my code above.

Comment: @Damian all my strings are greater than 6 characters. I did attempt the correction you have suggested with no luck.

Comment: Sorry @AAD.Ad i've missed a closing ")" it should be `Right(arrData(i, 3), Len(arrData(i, 3)) - 5)`

Comment: @Damian, it sort of works. I tried with getting ride of 13 characters but it gave me the following error " Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5) "

Comment: Then try any of the answers below

Comment: Not a problem thank you very much for all your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, Row As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

            For Row = 1 To Lastrow

                If Left(.Range("C" & Row).Value, 3) = "XXX" Then
                    .Range("B" & Row).Value = ""
                Else
                    .Range("B" & Row).Value = Mid(.Range("C" & Row).Value, 4, Len(.Range("C" & Row).Value) - 3)
                End If

            Next Row

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: your code has work, I do however receive an error [Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)] The code does work. Is there away to get rid of the Error? My file has over 65,000 rows

Comment: I ended up using your code and another one to format it further. I didn't keep track on where the code was. Nevertheless, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Sub KleanUp2()
    Dim cell As Range, v As String, v2 As String
    For Each cell In Intersect(Range("C:C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        v = cell.Value
        If Len(v) < 4 Then
            vr = ""
        Else
            vr = Mid(v, 4, 9999)
        End If
        cell.Offset(0, -1) = vr
    Next cell

End Sub
```

If the value in column **C** is more than 3 character, the first three characters are removed and the result placed in the same row in column **B**

If the value in column **C** is less then 4 characters *(or the cell is empty)*, then a null is placed in column **B** in the same row.